# Angular TypeError('readdirp: root argument must be a string.')

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I had a perfectly good angular app working on my laptop, then I decided to move the backend out to be standalone, and since then `ng serve` throws the following error.  It seems to get through the compile ok, and then throws an error from `readdirp` - anyone know whats going on?

```
Date: 2020-05-19T19:20:23.850Z - Hash: d2eb790e660ef9dbe323 - Time: 10777ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.
C:\__FILES\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\readdirp\index.js:252
    throw new TypeError('readdirp: root argument must be a string. Usage: readdirp(root, options)');
    ^
```

Google doesn't seem to know much about this. I've updated my npm packages to the latest versions on everything.  Here is my package.json in case it helps:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/elements": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.7",
    "@mapbox/tilebelt": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.7",
    "@types/google.visualization": "0.0.52",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^1.10.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "document-register-element": "^1.7.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.10.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^5.0.2",
    "karma": "^5.0.8",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.2"
  }
```

Edit:
If I build it and serve it, no problems, and seems to get through the dev compile ok.  So something to do with serving the develepment app?

Comment: delete `node_modules` folder and do `npm i` it could reproduce error. you can try to remove caret (^) from version and reinstall dependencies maybe you catch some bug with latest patch version

Answer (score 1):

@Radik had the right approach. I deleted `node_modules`, `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, took an old `package.json` from before I deleted the backend and did an `npm install`.  Instead of deleting the lines I didn't need from the `package.json` as I did last time, this time I did `npm uninstall` on each package and ran `ng serve` after each to make sure it still worked.  Then I ran `npm outdated` and updated each package using `npm install xxx@latest`.  Finally I did `npm prune`.  I can't say which step fixed the problem, but its working fine now.

Comment: I came here with the same problem but running React; removing node_modules and re-running npm install did it